# BluetoothLE как создать пару с сенсором, требующим пинкод

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, android-bluetooth

После сканирования получаю соединение с найденным прибором. Все стандартно: читаются сервисы и характеристики, посылается ответ и прибор спарился.  Так это все хорошо работало, пока не понадобилось присоединить прибор, который требует пин-код. Теперь после того, как отправляю ответ, вылазит окно, которое требует пин-код.
Вопрос: как получить отклик от этого окна? Как узнать, был ли введен пинкод правильно?

Comment: а зачем "отклик от этого окна"? Разве после успешного ввода пинкода не срабатывает метод onConnectionStateChange у callback-а?

Comment: нет, он срабатывает раньше, я же уже читаю инфу из DeviceCharacteristic и шлю ответ, и только потом появляется это окно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oбработать событие от BluetoothDevice onBondstateChange.